# Named entity recognition : For new/latest entities

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

Sorry for that weird "question title" , but I couldnt think of an appropriate title.

Im new to NLP concepts, so I used NER demo (http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/ner/results.php). Now the issue is that "how & in what ways" can I use these taggings done by NER. I mean these what answers or inferences can one draw from these named-entities which have been tagged in certain groups - location, person ,organization etc. If I have a data which has names of entirely new companies, places etc then how am I going to do these NER taggings for such a data ?

Pls dont downvote or block me, I just need guidance/expert suggestions thats it. Reading about a concept is another thing, while being able to know where & when to apply it is another thing, which is where Im asking for guidance. Thanks a ton !!!

A snippet from the demo:-

Dogs have been used in cargo areas for some time, but have just been introduced recently in 
passenger areas at **LOC Newark**  and **LOC JFK**  airports. **LOC JFK**  has one dog and **LOC Newark**  has a 
handful, **PER Farbstei**n  said.

Answer (score 2):

Usually NER is a step in a pipeline.  For example, once all entities have been tagged, if you have many sentences like `[PER John Smith], CEO of [ORG IBM] said...`, then you can set up a table of Companies and CEOs.  This is a form of [knowledge base population](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/kbp/).

There are plenty of other uses, though, depending on the type of data you already have and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So for example Ive got 1million tweets of people talking about a apple-mobile, and I want to categorize them into info-sharers, discussing price, enquiring about availability etc. Then in this case I suppose there wont be much larger Knowledge Base. Also then in this case how can NER help me in being an intermediate step to solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that NER will help you in that use case.  What you're trying to is called document classification.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification 

Especially if you can select a small enough group of categories.  You could use NER as a feature in your classifier, but if you already know for example that all your tweets are about apple, then I don't know that you'd gain anything from it.

Comment: Thansk aelfric, thats why I was confused about NER when sumbdy suggested me. Whilst my case here is just classification of tweets in 3/4 categories, could also give some cases when NER is helpful. I.e. what kind of probs is it helpful in & where to use it,how it assists etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two parts in your question:

**What is the purpose of NER?**

This is vast question, generally it is used for Information Retrieval (IR) tasks such as indexing, document classification, Knowledge Base Population (KBP) but also many, many others (speech recognition, translation)... quite hard to figure out an extensive list...

**How can we NER be extended to also recognize new/unkown entities?**

E.g. how can we recognize entities that have never been seen by the NER system. In a glance, two solutions are likely to work:

- Let's say you have some linked database that is updated on a regular basis: than the system may rely on generic categories. For instance, let's say "Marina Silva" comes up in news and is now added to lexicon associated to category "POLITICIAN". As the system knows that every POLITICIAN should be tagged as a person, i.e. doesn't rely on lexical items but on categories, and will thus tag "Marina Silva" as a PERS named entity. You don't have to re-train the whole system, just to update its lexicon.
- Using morphological and contextual clues, the system may guess for new named entities that have never been seen (and are not in the lexicon). For instance, a rule like "The presidential candidate XXX YYY" (or "Marina YYY") will guess that "XXX YYY" (or just "YYY") is a PERS (or part of a PERS). This involves, most of the times, probabilistic modeling.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks pal that was great insight. Could you also help me with some relevant "tutorial/how to/lecture" on these two points. As far as Ive searched I could get only some research articles which were very difficult to grasp. So please if you could , thats the only help I need. Thanks pal !!!

Comment: I believe this article http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/aiweb/media/papers/tmpcLeDnr.pdf gives a quite large and easy-to-follow overview of Named Entity Recognition aims and techniques